# JS Scoping issue where 2 variables don't seem to behave the same

Tags: javascript, scope

The following bit of code is troubling me:

```
define('TodoItem', function()
{
    var Component = require('Component')
    var app = require('application').app
    var merge = $.extend

    var TodoItem = Component.extend(
    {
        template : 'todo-item-template',

        events :
        {
            'button.completed click'    : 'markAsCompleted',
            'button.delete click'       : 'remove'
        },

        getInitialState : function()
        {
            var initial =
            {
                uuid        : undefined,
                text        : '',
                completed   : false
            }

            return initial
        },

        markAsCompleted : function(evt)
        {
            if (this.root)
            {
                var test = merge({}, this.getInitialState(), { whatever : 'whatever' })
                app.completeTodo(this.model.uuid)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the time `markAsCompleted()` is executed, `merge` is called without surprises, but somehow, the call to `app.completeTodo()` throws a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'completeTodo' of undefined`(and app is indeed `undefined`).

`app` being a reference to an object, the only way its value changed is if the referenced object changed in the meantime. And yet `require('application').app` still evaluates to the object it should.

It seems like a simple JS issue I'm misunderstanding but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where is `markAsCompleted ` called your code?

Comment: it's not possible to tell completely from your code - but it might be that the require code is running asynchronously - so require('application').app is undefined when you are assigning it to app.  What does require() do?

Comment: Yes, markAsCompleted() was called asynchronously. 

Fixed now : I had indeed checked that require('application') was called before (and it was) and that it was indeed defined but I slapped the .app later on and forgot to check _its_ value.

Thanks guys and sorry